# PHP class 'Ds\Map' not found

Tags: php

In PHP (version 7.1), I am attempting to use a MAP as opposed to a two dimensional array to handle implicit data type conversion across different data type groups. However, I am receiving the following run-time error:

> Class 'Ds\Map' not found

The error occurs on this line of code:

```
protected $hive_data_type_group_map = new \Ds\Map();
```

I have checked online, but there is little documentation on Ds\Map, even on PHP's website ([click here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.ds-map.php)). Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: Data Structures (ds) extension is not built-in in PHP. Did you [install it](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ds.installation.php) ?

Comment: @LexLustor That appears to be the problem. I won't know for sure as I will need to reach out to the DBA's when they are available. Thank you for the quick response. If you want to post it as the answer I will check it.

Comment: Glad it helped. I posted an answer, but it's barely an answer. Feel free to close your question if you like.

Comment: As far as I know, all builtin classes belong to the root namespace.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[Data Structures](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.ds.php) is not a built-in PHP extension.

It needs to be installed before use. The installation instructions are [available on php.net](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ds.installation.php).

Comment: for those who use Laravel you can ad dependency in composer to `php-ds`(like you do with say `laravel/laravel`)

Comment: In Ubuntu you probably have package for this. Search with 
`sudo apt-cache search php-ds`

Answer (score 1):

For windows

Download compiled-dll file "php_ds.dll" from https://pecl.php.net/package/ds. Place it in your dir wamp\bin\php\[your_php_version_folder]\ext and include it in your ".ini" file.

It worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

the easiest way on ubuntu:

```
pecl install ds
```

Reference: https://www.php.net/manual/en/ds-deque.allocate.php